# docker nginx access log permission denied

Tags: docker

I want create volumes with `/var/log/nginx`. I get this error message.

> [crit] 7#7: *16 open() "/var/log/nginx/access_2018-10-11.log" failed
>   (13: Permission denied) while logging request,

If I modified `nginx/log` permission to 777, it's work. But I think it's not good solution. How can I fix it? thanks your help.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx/
        volumes:
          - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
          - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
        links:
          - php
        ports:
          - 9999:80
        restart: always
...
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.13.3

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim

ADD ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

...

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';


    map $time_iso8601 $logdate {
        '~^(?<ymd>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})'   $ymd;
        default                         'nodate';
    }

    access_log '/var/log/nginx/access_${logdate}.log' main;

...
}
```

Comment: FYI: [issue #113 "Permissions issue (using compose)"](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/113)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could as I see it:

- Either detect the UID (GUID) of the user nginx is running as (`nginx` by [default](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/mainline/alpine/Dockerfile#L54)) and allow access to the directory only for the user or group.

  Typically the owner would be the user from the host and a group owner would be mapped to GUID from the guest. Then the access level of 770 is sufficient for the directory involved.
- Or you can drop the idea of logging to a flat file directly and let nginx container to reroute the logfiles to `stdout` and `stderr` as it does by [default](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/mainline/alpine/Dockerfile#L136) and capture/debug/monitor/write-to-file them from the host via [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) facility